# Error in UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

Do you know why it's happening?

[image: code & error message]

Comment: EnterPhoneNumber ?? According to naming convention rename it to phoneNumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy, use [EnterPhoneNumber text] instead!

Answer (score 0):

"`EnterPhoneNumber`" appears to be a "`UITextField`" object.

To get at the actual string, you need to do "`EnterPhoneNumber.stringValue`" in that "`initWithFormat`" method call.

Also, just a F.Y.I.:  if you want to follow best practices in Objective C, variables should start with **lower case letters** (i.e. change "`EnterPhoneNumber`" to be "`enterPhoneNumber`").

Answer (score 0):

You should use EnterPhoneNumber.stringValue, not that textfield itself.